# Use iphone to remotely complete a circuit

Tags: iphone, controls, wireless

I want to create IBAction for the iPhone or iPad that wirelessly or remotely cause a circuit to complete. So again. I am not sure what API I need to use. I need help to connect the IBAction to the process. Please any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you have specific hardware and an SDK in mind to complete the circuit or are you creating that part yourself?

Comment: If VenDiaS were to provide just a bit more detail, this would be a perfectly valid question.

Answer (score 2):

The iPhone doesn't contain a specific API for controlling external devices.  You need to refer instead to the user manual or data sheet of the device you are attempting to control.

If you use a networked device, such as the make controller or Ethernet shield on an arduino, you can use networking commands to control the circuit.

We can give more specific help if you explain more about what you are controlling, and whether you already have hardware to act as a gateway between the iPhone and the device you are controlling.